# Unknown icon before logon screen

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth, login, windows-hello

Recently I have installed [Samsung Flow](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/samsungflow/) because I wanted to try specifically the "unlock with fingerprint sensor" function. Basically my phone is connected to my PC over Bluetooth, and when I unlock my phone (fingerprint sensor) while my PC is on the logon screen, my PC gets unlocked as well. Pretty nice feature, I've decided to uninstall it though. So I uninstall both driver and application, except it's not completely gone.

Everytime I start my PC, I get this icon before seeing the logon screen itself. It appeared with the installation of Samsung Flow, but didn't disappear with the uninstallation. Since I can't take screenshots while my PC is starting, I've taken a photo with my phone and reconstructed the icon:

[image]

**Does anybody know what this icon is?** I was hoping a reverse Google image search could help (since it practically looks like the original icon), but no results.

Note: I think Samsung Flow "kindof" uses Windows Hello, since when I used the fingerprint sensor, I would get the Windows Hello logo (:)) with "Hello (my name)", but in the settings it would tell me that Windows Hello is unavailable on my PC (I'm running Win10 Home)

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the question up in case someone needs it in the future.

I've fixed the problem by clearing the TPM:

1. Windows Key + R -> TPM.msc
2. Choose "Clear TPM" in the top right corner
3. Your PC will restart. BIOS/UEFI will ask you if you want to clear the TPM. Follow the instructions to clear it (I had to press F12 to confirm it).